# Query- Find no. of closed tickets from no. of tickets created

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query that finds number of ticket created by an agent per queue(department).

```
SELECT queue.name AS 'Queue', COUNT(ticket.id) AS '# of tickets'
FROM ticket
    INNER JOIN
        queue ON ticket.queue_id = queue.id
WHERE
    ticket.create_by != 1
AND
    DATE(ticket.create_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day)
AND
    ticket.queue_id IN ( SELECT id FROM queue WHERE valid_id=1 ORDER BY name)
GROUP BY queue.name;
```

What i want is to get how many tickets are closed from the tickets created. here is the structure of the result of above query:

```
Queue         ||      # of tickets


Billing                12
Enterprise Support     7
Fiber Support          47
L2-Support             4
Retail Support         107
Sales                  4
```

I am not so good in subqueries. thats why i am struggling in this query.
the following query shows the number of tickets that are in closed state

```
    SELECT queue.name AS 'Queue', COUNT(ticket.id) AS '# of closed tickets'
    FROM ticket
        INNER JOIN
            queue ON ticket.queue_id = queue.id
    WHERE
        ticket.create_by != 1
    AND
ticket.ticket_state_id = '2'
    AND
        DATE(ticket.create_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day)
    AND
        ticket.queue_id IN ( SELECT id FROM queue WHERE valid_id=1 ORDER BY name)
    GROUP BY queue.name;
```

Ultimately i want to display no of tickets created by the queues and how many tickets are in closed state like this:

```
Queue         ||      # of tickets       || # of closed tickets



Billing                12                    2
Enterprise Support     7                     0
Fiber Support          47                     22
L2-Support             4                      1 
Retail Support         107                     60
Sales                  4                       1
```

Comment: Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements and a desired result

Comment: @Strawberry Is it not clear??? Its clear enough that any one can understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to aggregate both the set and its subset do it with `CASE`

```
SELECT queue.name AS 'Queue', COUNT(ticket.id) AS '# of tickets'
  , SUM(CASE WHEN ticket.ticket_state_id = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '# of closed tickets'
FROM ticket
    INNER JOIN
        queue ON ticket.queue_id = queue.id
WHERE
    ticket.create_by != 1
AND
    DATE(ticket.create_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day)
AND
    ticket.queue_id IN ( SELECT id FROM queue WHERE valid_id=1 ORDER BY name)
GROUP BY queue.name;
```

Comment: Note that the ORDER BY clause is redundant.